# Remove Columnmenu.columns from kendo ui grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i'm working with KENDO UI Grid today, i need in a grid that in the columnmenu there are active the item "sort ascending, sort descending, columns, filter", but i need also that "columns" item disappear in the other columns, so that ppl can only hide from the first column.
For example, 
in this code

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columnMenu:true,
    filterable: true,
    sortable: true,
    columns: [
        { field: "productName" },
        { field: "category" }
    ],
    dataSource: [
       { productName: "Tea", category: "Beverages" },
        { productName: "Coffee", category: "Beverages" },
        { productName: "Ham", category: "Food" },
        { productName: "Bread", category: "Food" }
    ]
});
</script>
```

the result would be that in every column i'll get a menù with 4 item:

1. sort ascending
2. sort descending
3. columns
4. filter

now i need that only for "productName" column there are all 4 voices, and for "category" column (and for every other possible column), menu voice contain only:

1. sort ascending
2. sort descending
3. filter

is that possible?

ty for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to configure this directly but you can remove the 'columns' menu entry on the Grid's `columnMenuInit` event (see http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-columnMenuInit):

```
columnMenuInit: function(e) {

  // Only remove if column is not 'productName'
  if (e.field != "productName") {
    // Remove the item from the menu via JQuery
    e.container.find(".k-columns-item").remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: There is also a way to remove productName from the list of the hideable column? @Daniel